# Project Fails After NUGET Packages Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Updating dependencies using NUGET creates errors in application.

Creating a new project from Visual Studio Community 2017 for C# and Web Forms with a master page. After successfully running the website inside Visual Studio, I update the project and find 24 nuget packages needs updating.

So OK, Update the packages. All 24 and restart Visual Studio as instructed.

Reload the project and run, I get a compilation error and the project fails to run or complete loading.

This compilation error is new, previously I lost my connection to twitter/bootstrap and jquery files. I fixed those by removing the references in the script and bundle manager.

Now it just kills the fresh application template. There is no programming, just the basic template fails to load. And when it did blew up most of the bootstrap and jquery routines and destroyed the navigation menu layout.

Here is the Compilation error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS > Express>C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\Documents\Visual Studio > 2017\Projects\WebSite2\WebSite2\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library > /utf8output /nostdlib+ > /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\c9841997\00b21bea_1de6d301\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\2c48699e\0011ed8c_808dce01\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\ca88605b\00cb5b40_b9c3d301\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\0f5ed648\00720de7_d9cccd01\Owin.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\ed6e8f5b\008a9d1a_f395d301\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\c5b71904\002397f9_6c18cf01\WebGrease.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\7cb43f83\00d0a76d_64aece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\6a7a0b6e\001e1df5_ebdbd301\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\3cbaac25\00f1ebf3_ebdbd301\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\de563d64\0097c37f_224cd301\EntityFramework.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\713924f7\00c4f480_224cd301\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\e60bcda8\00939497_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\4fffbea8\00dfcf92_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll" > /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http.WebRequest\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\fb841881\00dfcf92_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\442f60b0\00583c8f_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\56334a44\0052dd57_a7e7ce01\System.Web.Providers.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\3f088bba\00393295_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\e1ab0c9e\00e6fa3f_7827cf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\3b868cfc\00b29e91_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\e9625208\00e6fa3f_7827cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\11064a60\00666396_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\a6149561\00fbad02_86f3d301\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\aa9c70b3\00fed98c_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\cb06e281\004a1588_11a5d301\Microsoft.Owin.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\3101006c\00d6d5b9_2dabce01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\4f6eecce\00b7cbbf_2dabce01\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll" > /R:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\assembly\dl3\d9915d1f\001e1df5_ebdbd301\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" > /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" > /out:"C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ > /optimize- /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 > /langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 > "C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.0.cs" > "C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.1.cs" > "C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.2.cs" > "C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.3.cs" > "C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.4.cs" > "C:\Users\michaelw.DEESIGN\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET > Files\vs\732bd14c\5c4cc4da\App_Code.clskvtg9.5.cs"

### All this from a basic template that was just "updated" in Nuget.

1) Can someone tell me what has gone wrong? And how do I fix it the right way.

1a) Can someone show me how bundles and scriptmanager is supposed to load jQuery and bootstrap?

2) Is this common for package updates to kill a project or break what was previously working?

3) Is there a way in the future for "updates" to behave correctly?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Revert the package updates and update the packages one at a time, checking the release notes for compatability issues.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I deleted and removed the webforms package and restarted a new webform project from the provided template. It compiled and ran as advertised and as I expected. I began the process of installing the 24 updates, one at a time. ANTLR updated without issue. Asp.Net.ScriptManager.Bootstrap caused bootstrap to not load correctly. Starting again from scratch, This time I went to do just bootstrap and not the ScriptManager and I got both due to dependency and again This cause boostrap to not properly load, and the most apparent issue is that the bootstrap menus are now all collapsed.

Comment: I am still looking for the culprit as to what is throwing the Compilation Error. First I need to fix the bootstrap update as this will more than likely be the same fix as the jQuery update fix. Odd that I seem to be the only person on the planet having this problem.

Comment: @MichaelWood, Thanks for your reply. According to your reply, it seems it is OK when you update those nuget packages, one at a time. Now your issue should be more related to **ScriptManager**. This should be another question, and more related to ASP.NET, ScriptManager, so I suggest that you could open a new thread about this specify question with ScriptManager tag, you will get better support. If the answer resolve your nuget question, you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we could close this thread.

Comment: @Leo Liu I accepted the answer below as it does resolve the nuget issue, or at least help me determine where the break is. And I will look for / post a question on the ScriptManager and go from there. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can someone tell me what has gone wrong? And how do I fix it the right way.

You should use [NuGet Package Manager UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui) to update those nuget packages, the **Updates** tab displays packages with higher versions. You could check the checkbox `Select all packages`, then click `update` button to update all packages.

[image]

In this way, NuGet will check for dependency compatibility, if there is any issue during updating, NuGet will revert the package updates. And you can check the logs in the output window to find why the update failed. Alternatively, we can also update those packages one by one, check the log for the compatibility issues.

> 2) Is this common for package updates to kill a project or break what
>   was previously working?

No, but it is common for package updates to break what was previously working. That because each package has its own dependencies and other restrictions. When we update one of the package, NuGet will update its dependencies, but if other package depends on the old dependencie, then it will break what was previously working. But just as I said above, NuGet will give the warning/error info in the output window when you update the package in the Visual Studio in the most case and NuGet will revert the package updates.

> 3) Is there a way in the future for "updates" to behave correctly?

If above two questions resolve your question, this question does not need to be answered. If above not resolve your question, please give me some steps how did update the nuget packages, I will keep follow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As of this writting and using https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms/ as a go by to add bootstrap and jquery to a webforms still they are not loading properly. On another project I "fixed" this by removing the ScriptManager and bundle references and loading the scripts and Css the old fashioned way.....

Comment: I have monkeyed with this some today. No Joy. Evdn after manually loading the bootstrap and jquery, the project fails as I get the error "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)" and I forgot how I got around this the last time. It is VERY UNFORTUNATE that "simply" updating supporting files breaks a functioning project to the point where it takes several and many varied hoops to make the project run again.